# Unable to create an OpenSSL project with CLion

Tags: c++, openssl, c++17, clion, cmakelists-options

I am trying to create a simple OpenSSL poject in CLion but it can suceed in linking it.

This is my final CMakeLists.txt file (after many tries) which gives less errors:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(duplicates_finder)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -L . -lssl -lcrypto")


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
if (OPENSSL_FOUND)
    # Add the include directories for compiling
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

    # Add the static lib for linking
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)

    message(STATUS "Found OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")

else()

    message(STATUS "OpenSSL Not Found")

endif()

include_directories(C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\include)
link_directories(C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\lib\\MinGW)
```

This is the file I am trying to compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

//string sha256(const string& str)
//{
//    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
//    SHA256_CTX sha256;
//    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
//    SHA256_Update(&sha256, str.c_str(), str.size());
//    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
//    stringstream ss;
//    for(unsigned char i : hash)
//    {
//        ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)i;
//    }
//    return ss.str();
//}

int main() {

    std::cout << "SSLeay Version: " << SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION) << std::endl;
    SSL_library_init();
    auto ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    if (ctx) {
        auto ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        if (ssl) {
            std::cout << "SSL Version: " << SSL_get_version(ssl) << std::endl;
            SSL_free(ssl);
        } else {
            std::cout << "SSL_new failed..." << std::endl;
        }
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    } else {
        std::cout << "SSL_CTX_new failed..." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And these are the errors:

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\USERNAME\CLionProjects\duplicates_finder\cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 8
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable duplicates_finder.exe
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\duplicates_finder.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to `SSLeay_version'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:43: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `SSLv23_client_method'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:46: undefined reference to `SSL_new'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:48: undefined reference to `SSL_get_version'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `SSL_free'
C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GC~1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/duplicates_finder/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [duplicates_finder.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\duplicates_finder.dir\build.make:87: recipe for target 'duplicates_finder.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/duplicates_finder.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/duplicates_finder.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I restared my PC.

I also added the line:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libeay32.lib) //also .a file the result is the same.
```

And it throws the error that it can't find that file.

Also added the files: libeay32.a, libeay32.def, libeay32.lib and ssleay32.a, ssleay32.def, ssleay32.lib to the project folder and also to the cmak-build-debug folder. => Still not working.

Also renamed libeay32.a to libeay32.dll.a and ssleay32.a to ssleay32.dll.a  as on the another topic from stackoverflow says but it is still not working too.

No matter I do it is not compiling at all.

I spent all day searching for a solution but in vain.

I am using Windows 7 x64 and OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is openssl built with mingw? You might find using Conan an easier way to manage dependencies

Comment: It has a folder inside include folder named MingW which include libeay32.a and ssleay32.a and their .def files. I think it is with MingW. What is Conan and how to use it? Coul you show a full step by step tutorial, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://conan.io/

Comment: Just coming back to say that I didn't find a solution. There are videos on YouTube about this tool but they are hours long and none of them shows how to make it work with CLion and how exactly it could help me in this situation. Any idea, please? Thank you in advance!